# Find links to images in HTML (incl. outside of common tags/attributes)

Tags: javascript, html, image, search, match

I'd like to find (using javascript) all of the references to image links on an HTML page. Since I'm also looking for image references that may not be displayed, or are in unknown attribute types, simply looking for image tags or src's etc. isn't enough.  As such, I haven't yet found a simple method using an html parser to do this.

Having looked through the stackoverflow threads, I don't want to lose my soul by employing the dark method of matching that dare not speak its name - I hesitate to mention it here, lest I draw down the fury of those who hate using regu1@r_expre$$i0n$ for such a purpose.   But I haven't found the right method yet either.

I know that all links that look like images links are not, and vice versa, but that's OK.  I don't need complete coverage, just the widest possible without sacrificing speed.  so I'm guessing that following all the links is too intensive, and restricting myself to links that 'look' like images will be just fine.

Comment: Can you give some example HTML source? Also, given that you are `looking for image references that may not be displayed, or are in unknown attribute types`, you are probably going to sacrifice speed.

Comment: You seem to be looking for anything matching `"[filename].[image extension]"` in the HTML code. If you're expecting these to come up in more places than just src attributes and img tags, you'll have to do some sort of searching over everything in the document. Why don't you want to use regular expressions? They seem perfectly suited for this application.

Comment: it does sound like regex would work here, but everything I have read suggest regex is almost always a horrible way to parse web pages, so I figure there must be a better answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anthony was right, regex worked just fine for my purpose here.